# UK visitor visa; misinterpreted friends and family in the UK question

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have attended my appointment so this might be too late to ask but people may have the same question as mine.

So i will be visiting the UK with my family for a holiday and visiting my UK boyfriend. When filling the form, I might’ve misinterpreted the “friends/family in UK” part. I ticked “yes” on my application, put his address and, ticked yes for visiting. When filling my family’s application, I ticked no because I think technically they’re not friends with him. Now it gets me worried because I’ll definitely visit him with my family. Would this cause a problem?

I also made a dumb mistake by pasting my generic itinerary for the travel details on my family and my applications. None of them specified we’ll visit my bf (other than my answer on the mentioned part above).

Additional info: we fund our own trip and stay in a hotel. BF is not a sponsor

Comment: It would have been better if there were no discrepancies between the applications, however it’s too late to change it now - all you can do is endure the post-submission anxiety everyone goes through until you receive the decision.

Comment: Note that, in British English, "my boyfriend" means a man with whom you're romantically involved. Your description of him as not knowing your family, and the fact that you're not staying at his place makes it seem like you just mean "my friend, who is male". (Though I can easily imagine situations in which you do mean "boyfriend".)

Comment: As for the question as a whole, I'm not sure it's a good match for this site. You're asking about a very specific combination of mistakes on your application and whether or not you get your visa will depend on your application as a whole, not just on these particular parts of it. Even if you come back and post an answer about whether you got your visa, you and we won't know for sure why you did or didn't get it.